# How to group files by date in File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I tried to group files by date in File Explorer in Windows 10. This was how it looked:

[image: Screenshot of File Explorer after grouping]

But, I wanted it to be grouped date wise, like 21 Aug, 20 Aug, 19 Aug, etc. instead of *Yesterday*, *Earlier this week*, *Last week*, *Earlier this month*, *Last month*, *Earlier this year* and *A long time ago*.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: If you want individual dates, you would need to show details and then sort in date order

Comment: On the View tab of the ribbon select *Group By* button then choose *(None)*.

Comment: @user1292580: He asked how to group, not un-group.

Comment: @Random Person: Thanks for suggested edit. I went with more concise instructions to avoid distracting from  the essential details of my answer. Even Microsoft doesn't think all those screenshots are necessary: [Show libraries in File Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-libraries-in-file-explorer-8b443cb0-e966-55d9-e0d3-f814fe2db95b)

Answer (score 2):

The easiet way to get the grouping you want is to create a *[Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/windows-libraries)* for the top-level folders(s) that contain the files you're interested in. To create a new `Library`, right-click in the background of the `Libraires` folder and select `New` > `Library`. Then add your desired folders:

[image]

### Note: If the `Libraries` folder is not visible in the `Navigation Pane`, select the `View` tab, and then select `Navigation pane` > `Show libraries`.

Libraries offer additon viewing options for the contents of their source folders (and all their sub-folders). These are accessed by right-clicking in the Library *background* & accessing the `Arrange by >` sub-menu. The views offered vary by the `Optimize this library for:` setting. *Regarless of the file type you are interested in, select `Pictures`*. A `Pictures` library offers `Month` and `Day` views:

[image]

The `Month` view presents ***`Stacks`***, virtual folders of items grouped on a common property value, in this case, the month portioin of the date modified:

[image]

When you open a month stack, only the items moidfied in that month are displayed, grouped by the date portion of `Date Modifed`:

[image]

The `Day` view groups all the items by the date portion of `Date Modified` value (no intermediate stack):

[image]

Comment: How to do this with a network share? -- When using the "hack" to include a network drive (https://tinsleynet.co.uk/2015/windows-10-library-folders/), by "Day" shows "This folder is empty."

Comment: I don't know offhand. I only have my laptop for testing -- no nework. My guess would be that the `Day` view somehow relies on information from the index...

Comment: The answer is available at https://superuser.com/q/1675272/138868 - one has to enable indexing for the network share.

Answer (score 1):

Xplorer2 can do it, but it's not free. It can even group by name similarities.
[image]

digiKam can also group by years and months
[image]

Comment: Please add a description how to group by **day**. xplorer² seems to be able to group by **date**, which shows "Modified: This year", but does not distinguish days.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already listing details on the View tab, look to the left of the Details option and change the Group by option to None. On the Sort by option, choose Date Modified and Descending. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzgX7.png).