# How to have date indexed by Synology for shared network drive

Tags: windows-explorer, synology

### Aim

I would like to have images grouped by date (as shown at https://superuser.com/a/1670789/138868).

### Environment

- I have my images stored on a Network drive
- The network drive is made available by Synology
- I enabled indexing as outlined at https://superuser.com/a/1822011/138868

### Issue

When following that solution, no date is recognized by Windows:

[image: January 1970 shown in Windows Explorer]

### Question

How can I have the [Windows Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/windows-libraries) offer grouping by date in connection with a Synology-offered network folder?